# Test the convergence of series ${1\over\sqrt n} - \frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

We need to test the convergence of this series $${1\over\sqrt n} - \frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$
I have tried this using all tests such as comparison test, d'Alembert's test, Rabbe's test and Cauchy tests but I could not crack it.
It is given by my math professor in my assignment.

Comment: What is the limit of this sequence?

Comment: the limit is not 0, it doesn't converge

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt n} - \frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n+1}}=-1$$
The series diverges by the [$n$th term test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth-term_test).